# How do you understand this sentence? "もうそろそろ何度目かの正直的な感じでしょ！！”

Tags: grammar, meaning

The context is about character(1) doubting character(2) whether or not she can kiss the main character because character(2) couldn't express her feelings to the main character, so character(2) said:

> もうそろそろ何度目かの正直的な感じでしょ！！

I interpreted it as:

> Surely it is a honest feeling for the umpteenth time!

I shortly gave up and checked the English translation which says

> It's sure to go well by now, you know!

- I'm not sure I understand what 何度目か means but I found this link: [How should I understand 何回目か in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80475/46733)
- I'm also pretty confused at 正直的, if 正直 were to be understood as "honest" why is 的 used?

Comment: Big Hint: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%89%E5%BA%A6%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%AE%E6%AD%A3%E7%9B%B4/#jn-91599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment says, this is a deformed version of the common idiom [三度目の正直](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%89%E5%BA%A6%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%AE%E6%AD%A3%E7%9B%B4) "third time lucky". It's common to "hide" a part of a well-known long cliché/proverb using なんとやら, etc (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40915/5010)). By not saying everything, you can convey a you-know-what-I-mean sort of sentiment. This 的な is just *-ish* or *-like*, but it is applied to 何度目かの正直 as a whole.